# How to use OpenFileDialog

Tags: vb.net, winforms, openfiledialog

I have two forms named `frmChooseDBase` and `frmMain`. `frmChooseDBase` is for choosing a file(a database file). Once he's done choosing the database, `frmMain` will load the database chosen from `frmChooseDBase`.
How can I do dat? any help.
Here's my sample codes:

```
Public Class frmChooseDBase
    Public sr As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            sr = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            Me.Hide()
            FrmMain.Show()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub FrmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Desktop\'" & frmChooseDBase.sr & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
        con.Open()


 FillDGView("SELECT [CCCD Loading Database] AS [Transaction Date], [F2] AS [Unit Number], [F3] AS [Category], [F4] AS [Temp Required (C)], [F5] AS [Type Length], [F6] AS [T-State], [F7] AS [Position], [F8] AS [I/B Actual Visit], [F9] AS [Fright Kind] FROM [Loading$]")

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you just want to load a file, you don't need to make a new form. Just have a button or menu item that says load DB. Clicking that will pop an OpenFileDialog. Drag an openFileDialog control onto the form and give it a meaningful name (openFileDialog1...)

```
openFileDialog1.Title = "Please select a DB file"
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
openFileDialog1.Filter = "DB Files|*.extensionHERE"

If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK then
    'Do things here, the path is stored in openFileDialog1.Filename
    'If no files were selected, openFileDialog1.Filename is ""  
End If
```

There are plenty of examples for using the openFileDialog control if you get stuck, or need quick help.

Comment: Ok, so instead of getting da name of the file. Maybe its better to get the filepath bcoz I want to replace it in DataSource of the connectionString. Check dis, con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & [THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PASTE THE PATH] & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"

Comment: @Fvcundo Just pop a messgebox and see what Filename contains, I think it might actually contain the full path name.

Comment: @Fvcundo No worries mate!

Answer (score 5):

You don't even have to use a control:

```
Dim ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
ofd.DefaultExt = "txt"
ofd.FileName = "defaultname"
ofd.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
ofd.Filter ="All files|*.*|Text files|*.txt"
ofd.Title = "Select file"
If ofd.ShowDialog() <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
    MsgBox(ofd.FileName)
End If
```

Comment: I want to pass what was chose from the OpenFileDialog to connectionString. like this, con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Desktop\'" & [FROM WHAT I CHOSE FROM OPEN FILE] & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"